# Mysql in Python Query 2 or Parameters

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I am trying to send two parameters in my sql search using python. When I run the query in sql workbench it gives me the right result. Like the following:
Command used:

```
Select Name, Rating
From Restaurant 
Where Location = "جوہر ٹاؤن" AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID 
                                                  FROM Cuisine 
                                                  WHERE Name = "چائنيز") 
ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 3;
```

What im trying to do is send a value that user enters using the variable location and cousin.
This is the query I am getting an error on.

```
query = "Select Name From Restaurant Where Location = '%s' AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = '%s' ) ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 3;" % (location,cuisine)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
query = "Select Name From Restaurant Where Location = {} AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = {} ) ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 3;". format(location, cuisine)
```

For both cases that I have tried my query returns empty. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the error you are receiving.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '} AND RestaurantID IN (SELECT RestaurantID FROM Cuisine WHERE Name = {} ) ORDER ' at line 1

Comment: You should not be using string interpolation to build your queries. You are a getting an error building your string, look into parameterized queries. Can you also let us know what version of Python you are using and the error from your first query?

Comment: Using the first query I had the same error. I am using python 3.6.9.